# Handling errors with the Ember Data JSON-API adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, json-api

Errors on attributes located within related models is now my problem. I can see the errors on these related models by doing model.errors.content or model.errors.messages but if I want to check a particular attribute on a related model in order to highlight field errors I get null or undefined values.

See below screen shot for more info

Invaild Error object: [image]

Model After error: In this object i am getting the attribute and message but i use model.get("errors.phone"

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show what response your backend is giving, when validations fail? I suspect your error json is in wrong format

Comment: Did you include your validations mixin?

Comment: please specify your ember and ember-data versions.

Comment: {"errors":{"phone":["is invalid"]}}

Yes i have included validation mixin

Ember : 1.13.13
Ember-data : 2.2.1

Comment: Did you ever find the reason for this?  I am finding myself in somewhat the same boat.  My errors are not being populated as I expect.  I am using the correct JSON API format expected.

Comment: i have used model.errors.content it will return an array i used that array to display my error message

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is, you need to update your error serializer to send data in a format expected by Ember Data JSON Adapter.

It's best explained in detail in
[this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32059528/2664779), but as a gist you should format your data in a following way:

```
{
  "errors": 
  [
    {
      "detail": "is invalid",
      "source": {
        "pointer": "data/attributes/phone"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The pointer must correspond to your model attribute, so phone in this example.