# Handling errors with Ember Data JSON-API adapter not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a problem Handling errors using JSON-API, I done all steps like wrote in documentation but it's doesn't works.

I have model:

```
 var user = this.get('store').createRecord('user', {
    'email': 'test@test.com',
    'name': 'Lorem ipsum',
    'password': '123',
  });

  user.save().then(function(){
    ...
  }).catch(function(data){
    console.log(user.get('errors'), data);
    // data is ErrorClass  with deserialize errors inside
  });
```

And API responce (`422 Unprocessable Entity`):

```
    {  
   "errors":[  
      {  
         "detail":"Email address must be between 6 and 128 characters in length",
         "source":{  
            "pointer":"/data/attributes/password"
         }
      }
   ]
   }
```

In this case `isError` flag is `false`,  `user.get('errors')` -> `empty`

I also tried response with `500 Internal Server Error` code

In this case `isError` flag is `true` (as expected) and error object contain in `adapterError`

So what I'm doing wrong or what try to check,
thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36572090/how-to-display-error-message-in-ember-js-2-0/36721271#36721271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the `isError` flag, it shouldn't be `true` if you got Validation error (the one that has 422 code). It's described in [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_isError).

Your main problem is that you have a redundant forward slash in the beginning. So you have to change this `"pointer":"/data/attributes/password"` to this `"pointer":"data/attributes/password"`

After this change you'll be able to get the errors for this property through `user.get('errors.password');`

Hope it helps!