# Handling Ember model error w/ JSONAPI

Tags: ember.js, json-api

This has been answer for the MOST part here:
[Handling errors with the (now default) Ember Data JSON-API adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918565/handling-errors-with-the-now-default-ember-data-json-api-adapter)

I won't even go into how Ember docs stress to follow JSON API specs (http://jsonapi.org/format/), yet as far as I've read they don't even adhere to them (based off the answer linked to above)... but I digress!

I am not sure how to get errors into my model from the model() hook itself.

For example:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.get('store').findAll('page').catch(function(){});
    }
});
```

I am unable to access the errors in my template as such:

```
{{#each model.errors as |error|}}
    <div class="error msg_animate">{{{error.message}}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

I know I am missing a key factor here.
Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: typo: {{{error.message}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error response should follow the standard JSON API format,

http://jsonapi.org/format/#errors

Sample format,

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": "Error status",
      "code": 500,
      "message":"error message",
      "detail": "Some generic non property error message",
      "source": {
        "pointer": "data"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Most importantly, you need to include error function callback for Promise, 
Sample,

```
model() {
 return this.get('store').findAll('page').then(
     function(result){return result;},
     function(errors){ return errors; });
 }
```

Comment: The format was not the issue.  it was that I was not returning the errors from the promise.  Thx!