# How to access Ember JSON API errors within template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I have the following route model hook:

```
model() {
    return this.store.query('page').then(
        (result) => { return result; },
        (errors) => { return errors; }
    );
}
```

I am returning a basic error in my API so I can determine the best way to display errors when the API fails while attempting to populate the initial model.

The response is:

```
{
    "errors": [
      {
         "detail": "Test",
         "source": {
             "pointer": "data/attributes/general"
         }
      }
    ]
}
```

This is caught and I am left with a model that contains an ErrorClass.

[image: console error]

I expect the error above to be accessed by the "general" key, and be able to do the following in a template:

```
{{#each model.errors.general as |error|}}
    <div class="error msg_animate">{{error.message}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

But I am not able to access errors in this manner.
It seems that my error response isn't being parsed correctly because I can access the errors as such:

```
{{#each model.errors as |error index|}}
    <div class="error msg_animate">{{error.detail}} - {{error.source.pointer}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

This maps to the basic ErrorClass shown above and outputs:

```
Test - data/attributes/general
```

This is unexpected.  What am I missing?

**UPDATED INFORMATION**

I have the following that works in another route.  The difference being that it returns errors after attempting to save a model (rather than directly from the model() hook:

*template.hbs*

```
{{#each model.errors as |error|}}
    <div class="error msg_animate">{{error.message}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

*route.js*

```
actions: {
    submit: function(model){
        model.save().then((resp) => {
            this.transitionTo('admin.page-edit', resp.data.attributes.permalink);
        }, function(resp){
            // errors show on template
        });
    }
}
```

I am thoroughly confused as to the difference.  Both responses from my API seem exactly the same in terms of format.

Comment: if `model.errors` is an array then eaching `model.errors.general` doesn't really make sense, right?

Comment: How come doing the following won't work either?

`{{#if model.errors.general}}
     <div class="error msg_animate">{{model.errors.general.message}}    </div>`
    {{/if}}`

I'd expect this to work based on other things I've read on SO.  I could be way off of course.

Comment: think about it like `model.errors` is a list of errors so you can access the first one with `model.errors[0]` and if the first error had a general key you could access it like `model.errors[0].general` — handlebars each is designed to be used with list-like structures, not map-like structures

Comment: @Gurnzbot Inside hbs you can say `{{log 'model.errors - ' model.errors}}` ..that would print object in console. that should explain a lot.

Comment: @kumkanillam I didn't know this was a thing :)
I find that it logs the error object that is exactly what I passed from the JSON API backend.  Has a `detail` and `source -> pointer` keys.
I would expect to be able to access the errors from my model as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32059528/1803539).  However, that does not work.

Is the issue the fact that I am returning an error from my model() hook initially?  Should I be using an error substate instead of my initial template?

Comment: @Gurnzbot To be frank, i haven't done this before. In your screen shot,i can see `isAdapter:true` if that is set to true then your error responses are not parsed and set in model `errors` hash. so please ensure status code 422 should come.